# Entity Framework : how to add counter variable to its results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF query as shown here. I would need to get the list (x variable) with its counter (sequence), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, as another column

How do I achieve it?

```
List<ERP_Table> x = db.ERP_Table
                      .Where(e => e.INo == currINo)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Try something like `x.Append(x.Count())`

Comment: Or `x.Add(x.Count())` even; however, your question assumes that the database table is a single column of `ints`. This feels like you need a more generic solution.

Comment: Hi Peter, Is it possible i assign the counter value without having separate line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the index value on the [`.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-1)))) method.

```cs
List<ERP_Table> x = db.ERP_Table
                      .Where(e => e.INo == currINo)
                      .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Select((item, i) => new {Item: item, Index: i})
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: hi it unable to resolve 'Item', 'Index' ,what should be the values

Comment: Hi, sorry for the error on typing, I have edit the response. On other hand, the `item` will be the object of your `ERP_Table` entity that ef core readed